# How does Spartacus determine the order of Slots and Components to render on the screen?

Tags: accessibility, spartacus-storefront

Reason for Asking: Accessibility
I noticed that the components and slots seems to be rendered in a "random" behavior.
How do we ensure the rendering order of slots and components to ensure our site is adhering to the Accessibility standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the order of page slots by providing a `LayoutConfig` to your `ConfigModule`.

See here: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/page-layout/